# Feedback form with the asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, feedback

i need to generate feedback form in html (aspx) with the aspx.cs code?
Can any one give some simple form?

Answer (score 0):

You have a long way to go.

Firstly, ASP is very different from ASP.NET and ASP does not have ASPX.CS pages (ASP.NET does). I am not sure why you put the `mail` tag in your question. But, once you have received feedback from your respondent, you probably want to store it some place, usually into a database (ASP.NET usually is paired with MS SQL databases). It sounds to me like you don't know or fully understand the project requirements. I think you should inquire more about it.

If you are doing ASP.NET here are some sites with lots of examples:

- http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-9640.aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp
- http://www.webcontinuum.net/dotnet_webform.aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_examples.asp

If you are doing ASP here are some sites with examples:

- http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_examples.asp
- http://www.example-code.com/asp/default.asp